# having issue while trying to use model route binding with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

By using this code I'm trying to return the post from posts table which has the same id by {post}.

```
Route::model('posts', 'Posts');
Route::get('post/{post}', function(Posts $post){
    return $post;
});
```

But It returns:

```
Argument 1 passed to {closure}() must be an instance of Posts, string given
```

What's the problem? (I'm a beginner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name in `Route::model` needs to match the parameter in your route:

```
Route::model('post', 'Posts');
Route::get('post/{post}', function(Posts $post){
    return $post;
});
```